# 5>> indents the next 4 lines including the current one. I want 5>> to indent the current line 5 times (vim, neovim specifically)

Tags: vim

I thought about

```
noremap 5>> >>4.
```

But naturally, it's not a good idea to just do this for every different number

Maybe there's some way to do input (say, 5) and then that input repeats in the command. I don't know how to do that either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
nnoremap <key> <Cmd>call repeat('>>', v:count1)->feedkeys()<CR>
nnoremap <otherkey> <Cmd>call repeat('<<', v:count1)->feedkeys()<CR>
```

Press `<key>` to shift one time, `5<key>` to shift five times, etc. It is up to you to choose `<key>` and `<otherkey>`. You could use `>>` and `<<` but that would override their default functionality, which I don't think is a good idea.

- `:help <Cmd>` makes it easy to execute built-in commands and functions from a mapping without unnecessary mode switching.
- `:help repeat()` outputs the given string repeated the given time.
- `:help feedkeys()` is a low-level way to simulate keystrokes.
- `:help v:count1` is the count you gave to the mapping.

Very personal mappings are the gateway drug to vimscript.